# Rails/ActiveRecord query for party visits at particular locations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I need to create a query for `party_visits` that are at a `location` which a `user` has permission to view. I have the following models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :location_permissions
  has_many :party_visits
end

class LocationPermission < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location
  belongs_to :user
end

class Party < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :party_visits
end

class PartyVisit < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :party
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :location
end
```

So the following works:

```
allowed_locations = current_user.location_permissions.map {|location_permission| location_permission.location_id}
party_visits = PartyVisit.where(location_id: allowed_locations)
```

The problem is sometimes `allowed_locations` is **very big**. Then the `PartyVisit` query is very inefficient. Is there a way to make this into 1 efficient Rails/ActiveRecord query? Possibly not involving a sub-select query? I'd love to write this in Rails without resorting to SQL.

Comment: Wish I could help - would love to learn this myself!

Answer (score 0):

You can make this query like this:

```
party_visits = PartyVisit.where(location_id:
  current_user.location_permissions.select(:location_id))
```

This will run a single database query, without loading intermediate results into memory.